# Mount error (112) : Host is down

Tags: raspbian, mount

I got this error message after an upgrade.

```
Mount error (112) : Host is down
```

Anybody know why?

My `mount` cmd worked before... My media center is down.

Comment: Do you have any remotely mounted filesystems?

Comment: Need. More. Info.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Please post an answer or accept an existing one. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was due to my NAS death...

Answer (score 1):

You state in your question

> My media center is down

You are using `nfs` to mount a remote filesystem, that is hosted on a remote server. That server has gone down for some reason, and so the `mount` command is unable to mount that filesystem, because it is unable to reach the host.  The server may be powered off, or the route to the server is broken.

Either go and turn the remote host back on, or ask the administrator of the remote server to turn it back on and it should work. If not, then check to see if your network configuration has changed, and that the server is reachable, by using either `ping` or `traceroute`.

Also see [Mount CIFS Host is down](https://serverfault.com/questions/414074/mount-cifs-host-is-down).